# Dynamic resource allocation using virtualization in cloud computing environment

Tags: java

Hi im doing a java project on ecplise for my diploma 6th sen.The project name is dynamic resource allocation using virtualization in cloud computing environment but we run the project on tomcat and its conncted to database and it does not need internt connection also.so how is it a java cloud project??

PLZ help and explain

Comment: How would we know?

Comment: Is it possible to connect to free cloud??

Comment: Tomcat is used to test your project locally before you going to deploy it on an actual cloud platform. Elaborate more for the specific answer.

Comment: for free cloud this might help [OpenStcak](https://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/dashboard-launch-instances.html)

Comment: Avinash L .One of my many doubt has been cleared thank u.